# React JS React Router Get Request Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have url in my react js site.I use react routes library for routing.

```
http://localhost:17086/Home/Index#/userList?s=1515&showAge=true
```

How can I read s and showAge properties,and i have grid and filter,sort data on it.Is it a good way to use a tag and use request for bind grid.

Comment: Did you read the docs? Here's an example, https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/query-params/app.js

Comment: yes i find solution i am using old version thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the route Params in the Props.

this.props.routeparams.